# How to mirror a window?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to mirror a window? I mean to make exactly same duplicate of window?

It would be useful for me if I can make one duplicate small and other one big and put it into separate desktop.

Answer (score 1):

This is to mirror a window to an IOS device, perhaps this may help you?

http://xscopeapp.com/guide